# PlayFramework - Error when deploying to Heroku (pgsql 'user' table)

Tags: java, postgresql, heroku, playframework, playframework-2.1

I have recently been writing an application using Play (great framework, can't really fault it). However, I'm getting a weird error when pushing the app to Heroku.

```
2013-08-12T15:52:17.641129+00:00 app[web.1]: [←[31merror←[0m] play - ERROR: synt
ax error at or near "user"
2013-08-12T15:52:17.744588+00:00 app[web.1]:   Position: 14 [ERROR:0, SQLSTATE:4
2601]
```

That's where it seems to be going wrong.
The weird aspect of the error is the fact I don't have any tables or references to 'user' in my SQL-related code (evolutions, models and even my database). Would it be an issue with something being cached?

Thanks in advance,
Adil

EDIT

I seem to have fixed the error:

- I deleted the evolution scripts, for some reason they were filled
  with data I didn't need (e.g sql scripts to create a 'user table')
- I updated all my references to the user table (even class names) to
  'AppUser' (this is changeable).
- I ran sql queries on the pgsql database directly, creating the tables manually.
- I then disabled the
  evolutions plugin and removed the jdbc username and password when
  committing to heroku.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that you really don't have any tables or columns that are named `user`?

Comment: Yes, 100% sure. I also checked the database for any errors too.

Comment: Too localized, and is already fixed by the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Postgresql has a default "user" table. I would recommend naming your table something else like member. It will conflict with it otherwise. Caps might work, or tildes `user`, but even then I'd recommend using a different name for the table. Wipe your table just in case there is an evolution backup.